# Скрипт, отображающий пользователей в онлайн

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте, есть форма авторизации, которая работает на сессиях, так же есть список юзеров, и естественно есть моя админка со списком этих юзеров, и как сделать скрипт который покажет мне кто онлайн?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В БД нужна таблица последних действий (user_id - id пользователя, upd - время последнего действия). При каждом действии в таблице обновляется значение upd для текущего пользователя. При отображении списка пользователей выводятся те, у которых upd меньше текущего на, скажем, минуту.

Comment: Спасибо суть ясна, сейчас буду реализовывать.

Comment: На практике столкнулся с таким вопросом:
Создал переменную  
$time = date("H:i:s");  = 13:28:58  
заношу её в базу в поле upd, теперь как поставить условие на время?то есть если есть действие в радиусе 5ти минут то выводить надпись он лайн?

Comment: сохраняйте лучше в unixtime, считать проще

Comment: Можно подробнее пожалуйста ? я учу php

Comment: функция time() в PHP возвращает текущую метку времени. http://www.php.su/functions/?time , т.е. это время в секундах, т.е. просто обычное число, из которого потом просто надо будет вычитать 60 сек.

Comment: Заносите в БД через `update online set upd=unix_timestamp() where id=$session_user_id`. Тогда проверять можно будет `select id from online where upd>unix_timestamp()-60` .

Comment: я не пойму эту функцию unix_timestamp(), она в переменную не хочет записываться и в базу не хочет заносится, может быть из за того что поле в базе upd = int ?
___

$res = mysql_query("UPDATE online SET upd='unix_timestamp()' WHERE userID='$_SESSION[id]'"); не изменяет ничего в базе...

Comment: upd = int - это правильно. unix_timestamp() - функция mysql, поэтому она должна фигурировать в запросе.

Answer (score 0):

Записывать, например, в базу отдельно тех, кто обращается к сайту (авторизованные).
При проверке удалять тех, кто по времени не обращался более, например, 10 минут. Вот и будет у вас парподия на - кто онлайн.

Answer (score 0):

В таблице пользователей завести колонку с датой последнего посещения. При переходе по ссылкам, пользователь отправляет запрос на обновление даты последнего посещения, а вы собственно смотрите допустим последние 3 минуты.