# Online-посетители на сайте

Tags: php

Как отслеживать общее количество посетителей на сайте, которые сейчас онлайн?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Народ на поиск совсем забил :(

- [Как реализовать вывод пользователей кто онлайн?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43617/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD)
- [Как отобразить имена пользователей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43625/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)
- [Скрипт, отображающий пользователей в онлайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29045/php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD)
- [Плагин-виджет: кто онлайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/78799/php-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD)

Comment: Короче через бд, все ясно.

Comment: Если надо быстро и только вывод количества поветителей онлайн, то можно и через сессии

Comment: Каким образом?